# Formatting numbers in tikz Math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

When using the math library in pgf/tikz, you can declare a variable to be int, in which case it automatically gets formatted as an integer.

The problem I'm having is that if the calculation involves large numbers, you can get the "dimension too large" error, which can be handled by using the fpu library. However, this seems to cause all numbers to be formatted as floating point.

Here's a minimal example, where all is well:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}

\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
   int \foo,\foobar;
   \foo = 2;
   \foobar = \foo^10;
}

\begin{align*}
  \text{foobar} &= \foobar\\
\end{align*}
```

However, changing the math environment to

```
\tikzmath{
   int \foo,\foobar,\foobaz;
   \foo = 2;
   \foobar = \foo^10;
   \foobaz = \foo^20;
}
```

produces a "dimension too large" error, and prints an incorrect value for foobaz.

This can be fixed by loading the fpu library, but at a cost in simplicity.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}

\tikzmath{
   int \foo,\foobar,\foobaz;
   \foo = 2;
   \foobar = \foo^10;
   \foobaz = \foo^20;
}

\begin{align*}
  \text{foobar} &= \foobar\\
  \text{foobaz} &= \foobaz\\
  \text{foobaz formatted} &= \pgfmathprintnumber{\foobaz}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that even though these are integer variables, they are printed as floating point unless they are explicitly formatted with \pgfmathprintnumber. If an elaborate section is typeset using this, it would become quite a tangle.

Is this the expected behavior? What is the standard way to get (large) integers formatted correctly by default?

Answer (score 1):

May be not as elegant as OP would expect, but declaring integer variables before `\tikzmath` by `\newcount`, and then using the value of such variables by prepending `\the` seems to work.

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}

\newcount\foo
\newcount\foobar
\newcount\foobaz
\tikzmath{
   \foo = 2;
   \foobar = \foo^10;
   \foobaz = \foo^20;
}

\begin{align*}
  \text{foobar} &= \the\foobar\\
  \text{foobaz} &= \the\foobaz\\
  \text{foobaz formatted} &= \pgfmathprintnumber{\the\foobaz}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful but you can just set up your own number format in such a way that it produces integers. This can be done by looking up the definition of `/pgf/fpu/output format/fixed` and doing a minimal damage manipulation. One can build in a switch that treats integers differently from nonintegers via `\pgfmathifisint`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format/fixed int/.code={%
        \def\pgfmathfloatparse@output@choice{F}%
        \def\pgfmathfloatparse@output{%
            \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{%
                \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}}{%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed@{\pgfmathresult}}%
        }%
    }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed int}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}

\tikzmath{
   int \foo,\foobar,\foobaz;
   \foo = 2;
   \foobar = \foo^10;
   \foobaz = \foo^20;
   \foobuz = (\foo+0.1)^20;
}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\begin{align*}
  \text{foobar} &= \foobar\\
  \text{foobaz} &= \foobaz\\
  \text{foobuz} &= \foobuz\\
  \text{foobaz formatted} &= \pgfmathprintnumber{\foobaz}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. However, you lose the ability to print floating point numbers. Right?

Comment: That's a good point. I modified the answer to distinguish between integers and nonintegers.

Comment: Thank you. So, should this be regarded as a bug in tikz? I'll report it if I can figure out where to do so.

Comment: I do not know how to report this but I would agree that this behavior is unexpected, meaning one could call it a but. After all you tell tikz explicitly that these are integers. Notice also that there is the "xint" package but of course it does not support the elegant tikzmath syntax (I think).